# NHibernate to SELECT with FOR SHARE in PostgreSQL

Tags: nhibernate, postgresql, locking

*Let me explain my scenario...*

Say I have two table: "Paths" and "Packages"
Paths table is consists of "PathId" "StartNode", "EndNode"
Packages table is consists of "StartNode", "DestinationNode", "Paths"

I am going to write a program which compute the path that route a package from start to destination, using whatever shortest path algorithm.

In order to make sure the paths settings are not changing while I compute the path, I believe I should use "SELECT * FROM Paths FOR SHARE" to obtain a share lock. So until the paths are computed and transaction is committed, the path start/end must not be changed, and at any point - the computed paths in the database is always valid.

**The question is**: I am writing the program C# with NHibernate, how do i get a share lock?
I have tried:

```
Session.QueryOver<Path>().Lock().Read.List()
```

but it does not do the magic.

Is `Session.CreateSQLQuery()` the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know NHibernate does not currently support SELECT...FOR SHARE, but it does support FOR UPDATE and FOR UPDATE NOWAIT (see [lock modes](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-locking)), which is of course more strict, but it would work.

Since NHibernate is an open source project you may [suggest this enhancement](http://jira.nhforge.org/) and of course implement it.

Comment: I don't think optimistic locking works. For the sake of simplicity let's assume the Packages.Paths is one-to-many mapped to Paths.PathId. However, as I am not modifying the Path object itself, but merely referencing to it, optimistic locking won't kick in.